# Bootstrap Menu Tabs "Jump" on mobile and tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm using Bootstrap to develop a menu for a client, but for some reason when I click certain tabs in mobile or tablet mode, the tabs "jump" to another location on the list and leaves an ugly space in between tabs. I made a .gif to show what I'm talking about.

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? I included my own HTML and CSS below. Keep in mind I'm using Bootstrap CSS and JS as well.

EDIT: I think it may have to do something with floats.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#waxing" role="tab"> WAXING </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#nail-art" role="tab"> NAIL ART </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#nail-enchancements" role="tab"> 
    <div class="hidden-xs"> NAIL ENCHANCEMENTS </div>
        <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"> NAIL ENH </div> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#children" role="tab"> FOR CHILDREN </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#vitamin-dip" role="tab"> VITAMIN DIPS </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#gel-services" role="tab"> GEL SERVICES </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#combo-services" role="tab"> COMBINATIONS </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pedicure" role="tab"> PEDICURES </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#manicure" role="tab"> MANICURES </a>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav-tabs{
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius: 3px 6px 0px 0px;

}

.nav-tabs > li {
float: right;
margin-bottom: -1px;
background-color: #fff;
margin:auto;
}

@media(max-width:992px){
    .nav-tabs > li {
        width:50%;
    }
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active {
    border-bottom-style:none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#menu-tabs .nav-link{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

#waxing li, #other li {
    line-height: 23px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I did it by explicitly setting the height of each `li`.

```
    @media(max-width:992px){
    .nav-tabs > li {
        height: 37px;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

I think my problem was that I assumed all the `li` will keep the same height when I click on the link (focus on the `a` tag) within each `li`. I know using the `float` property on elements that are not the same width and height may cause gaps between the elements, hence the ugly gaps and jumps in my original code.